# android - table layout alignment

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

[image]
How to align Product Name and Product Grade correctly. I retrieve the product name from db, since the name is too long the align was not in same position. Please help Thanks

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/birdnesttoppanel"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/preview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/newclick"
                android:text="Click here to view the picture" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6new"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductName1"
            android:text="@string/ProductName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductName2"
            android:text=":"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductName3"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6new1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductGrade1"
            android:text="@string/ProductGrade"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductGrade2"
            android:text=":"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductGrade3"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: The term "align correctly" can be interpreted in many ways. Be more specific, like: align both labels to left, to right, one above other...

Comment: @AndyRes. Thanks for the comment. If you see my screen shot you can see Product Name and Product Grade is in different place. I want both to align to left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its somehow hard to distinguish which labels correspond in XML file, but let me guess:

So, for the TableRows:

```
`android:id="@+id/tableRow6new"` and `android:id="@+id/tableRow6new1"`
```

change the grativity to left: **android:gravity="left"**

Also, I see both TableRows have a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center" >
```

Change their gravity to left too:  android:gravity="left"

Hope it will solve the issue.